# Reading JavaScript object properties

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following code in JavaScript

```js
var result = {
    'org.apache.struts' : '4567ty5y7u8j89hjk789',
    'firstName' : 'Thorpe',
    'surName' : 'Obazee'
}
```

When I try to read result:

```js
// this works
sys.puts(result.firstName) // returns Thorpe
sys.puts(result.surName) // returns Obazee
```

The problem comes when I read the other property

```js
sys.puts(result.org.apache.struts) // return an error
```

> Error: Expected 'TypeError: Cannot
> read property 'apache' of undefined

How should I read this so that I can access the information I put?

Comment: When you say "this works", I assume you didn't copy and paste the code, because your object literal in the question shouldn't be using the `=` symbol to separate the name and value (it should be a `:`).

Comment: @Andy E. haha. sorry about that . I was writing and not looking at the code. fixed.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of JavaScript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)? There is a section that explains how to [access object properties using the square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Accessing_properties).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to access properties whose names contain characters invalid for dot notation:

```
result["org.apache.struts"]
```

If you want to add further levels to your object so that you can use dot notation, you need to declare another object for each level, e.g.:

```
var result = {
    org: { apache: { struts: '4567ty5y7u8j89hjk789' } },
    firstName: 'Thorpe',
    surName: 'Obazee'
}

alert(result.org.apache.struts);
```

Comment: +1 - For further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain what's incorrect about my answer?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you're adding it as a whole key instead of another object, access it like `result['org.apache.struts']`.

Or you can change the way you create result:

```
var result = {
    org : {
        apache : {
            struts : '4567ty5y7u8j89hjk789'
        }
    }
    'org.apache.struts' = '4567ty5y7u8j89hjk789',
    'firstName' = 'Thorpe',
    'surName' = 'Obazee'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your variable has dots in it. I would guess that javascript mandates interpreting this as nested objects which are not really existing. So, use

```
result["org.apache.struts"]
```

to get the value.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use ':' between the labels and values of the object and define 'org.apache' as an object too. Like this:

```
var result = {
    org: {apache: {struts: '4567ty5y7u8j89hjk789'}},
    firstName: 'Thorpe',
    surName: 'Obazee'
}
```

If you want to us '`org.apache.struts`' as a real label, Andy E's answer is the solution.